# Which design pattern to use to hit multiple rest api

Tags: javascript, express, design-patterns

I have one question where I would need some help.

In my current application I need to hit multiple rest api (from express) to get data and to construct my page. 
Currently I am using promise.all to get the data from all  api end points. Any design pattern that I can put on top of it which can help me to decouple the application.

So, I would need to know which design pattern suits most to solve such kind of problem.

Any example would be more helpful for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the *solving it all by just coding a bit* design pattern

Comment: Yeah, I am asking the same question that, which design pattern I should use to resolve this issue.

Comment: `Promise.all()` should work just fine for multiple REST calls.  It is not clear at all what you're asking for.  Questions about code should nearly always show your code and that is always true when you're asking for a better way to do things than you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use **Facade Design Pattern**.
The Facade Pattern provides the user with a simple interface, while hiding it's underlying complexity.

The Facade pattern is well-suited for uniting disparate APIs into a single public-facing interface that connects with the other APIs behind the scenes. It's been in use in JavaScript for a long time, and you may have used it many times without even knowing it.

Below basic example of Facade Design Pattern:

```js
'use strict';

var Mortgage = function(name) {
    this._name = name;
};

Mortgage.prototype = {
    apply: function(amount) {
        var result = 'Mortgage approved';
        if(!new Bank().verify(this._name, amount)) {
             result = 'Mortgage denied';
        } else if(!new Credit().verify(this._name, amount)) {
             result = 'Mortgage denied';
        } else if (!new Background().verify(this._name, amount)) {
            result = 'Mortgage denied';
        }
        return this._name + ' has been ' + result + ' for a ' + amount + ' mortgage';
    }
};

var Bank = function() {
    this.verify = function(name, amount) {
        // Implementation
        return true;
    };
};

var Credit = function() {
    this.verify = function(name, amount) {
        // Implementation
        return true;
    };
};

var Background = function() {
    this.verify = function(name, amount) {
        // Implementation
        return true;
    };
};
```